# How many days does one have to wait before reusing a surgical or respiratory mask so that it is free of the SARS-CoV-2 virus?

Tags: covid-19, face-mask-respirator

I read the following in a private email:

> One of my neighbors emailed me and said he has a few masks that he uses and recycles them; he wears one, when done he carefully stores it into a sealed plastic bag, uses the next one, does the same, and eventually 7 or more days (or masks) later, he rotates back to the original one and repeats the entire cycle. He mentioned that his assumption is that after 7+ days, the coronavirus is probably neutralized.  I’m considering whether to adopt this method, or perhaps combine it with some combination of heat, ozone, and/or UV.

How many days does one have to wait before reusing a surgical or respiratory mask so that it is free of the [SARS-CoV-2 virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus_disease_2019)?

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/pNvYjG
- https://redd.it/fpv1wy

Comment: Duplicate of https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/21655/3414

Comment: At work we are told to through n95 mask in garbage at end of 8 hours. I'm bagging mine and taking them home just in case we run out in a month. Spanish flu lasted for three years. Everyone is living day to day and no one has projected further than extending lock downs by 14 or 21 days at a time.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks, interesting. in which country do you work if I may ask? In some French hospitals I'm told that used masks are kept in some storage room in case of penury.

Comment: I work in a warehouse in Canada. PPE is one of our product lines.

Comment: "penury" is an interesting word I had to look up. Reminds me of the "Great Depression" era which sadly looks like an option for our future without sound leadership and false pride &  prejudices take over. LA nurses were told to [reuse masks](https://www.latimes.com/california/story/2020-03-25/coronavirus-healthcare-workers-masks-gowns-reuse). The 3M's 8210 & 8511 N95 masks are uncomfortable at work so I'm sewing my own like other nurses are [told to do](https://www.propublica.org/article/medical-workers-treating-coronavirus-are-resorting-to-homemade-masks). Sewing alleviates self-isolate too!